# split string by spaces and colon but not if inside quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

having a string like this:

```
$str = "dateto:'2015-10-07 15:05' xxxx datefrom:'2015-10-09 15:05' yyyy asdf"
```

the desired result is:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => dateto:'2015-10-07 15:05'
    [1] => xxxx
    [2] => datefrom:'2015-10-09 15:05'
    [3] => yyyy
    [4] => asdf
)
```

what I get with:

```
preg_match_all("/\'(?:[^()]|(?R))+\'|'[^']*'|[^(),\s]+/", $str, $m);
```

is:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => dateto:'2015-10-07
    [1] => 15:05'
    [2] => xxxx
    [3] => datefrom:'2015-10-09
    [4] => 15:05'
    [5] => yyyy
    [6] => asdf
)
```

Also tried with `preg_split("/[\s]+/", $str)` but no clue how to escape if value is between quotes. Can anyone show me how and also please explain the regex. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
preg_split("~'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~", $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sZ8cA6/1)

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining `"~'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~"` I just understand parts of it and I would like to get it all

Comment: `'[^']*'` matches all the single quoted block and the following (*SKIP)(*F) makes the match to fail. and the following `|\s+` matches all the remaining spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Often, when you are looking to split a string, using `preg_split` isn't the best approach (that seems a little counter intuitive, but that's true most of the time). A more efficient way consists to find all items (with `preg_match_all`) using a pattern that describes all that is not the delimiter (white-spaces here):

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~(?=\S)[^'"\s]*(?:'[^']*'[^'"\s]*|"[^"]*"[^'"\s]*)*~
EOD;

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $m))
    $result = $m[0];
```

pattern details:

```
~                    # pattern delimiter

(?=\S)               # the lookahead assertion only succeeds if there is a non-
                     # white-space character at the current position.
                     # (This lookahead is useful for two reasons:
                     #    - it allows the regex engine to quickly find the start of
                     #      the next item without to have to test each branch of the
                     #      following alternation at each position in the strings
                     #      until one succeeds.
                     #    - it ensures that there's at least one non-white-space.
                     #      Without it, the pattern may match an empty string.
                     # )

[^'"\s]*          #"'# all that is not a quote or a white-space

(?:                  # eventual quoted parts
    '[^']*' [^'"\s]*  #"# single quotes
  |
    "[^"]*" [^'"\s]*    # double quotes
)*
~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA8hC4/1)

Note that with this a little long pattern, the five items of your example string are found in only 60 steps. You can use this shorter/more simple pattern too:

```
~(?:[^'"\s]+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")+~
```

but it's a little less efficient.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! A frew more things I would like to know: "but that's true most of the time" is there a rule of thumb or some link I can read about when/why to use which one? How did you write the REGEX? you got a tool to do that or you know regex rules and just write it down? if just writing it down: how did you learn regex rules?

Comment: @caramba: It's more a rule of thumb, but ideas behind are relatively simple: 1) when the delimiter must take in account this environment, the pattern becomes quickly complicated and inefficient (in particular if you need to check what are the characters before, or if you need to check the string until the end with a lookahead). 2) Sometimes it is more easy to define something by negation.

Comment: @caramba: About how I write a pattern in general comes with the knowledge, the practice and testing. For example a pattern like `(?:[^'\s]+|'[^']*')*+` is more efficient if you "unroll" it, like this: `[^'\s]*(?:'[^']*'[^'\s]*)*+`, you can find this information in the Friedl book, but you can also see it with regex101 or regexbuddy that display the number of steps needed. But even with knowledge and recipes, you always need to experiment, in particular you must well know your enemy: the string.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\d)`, i.e.:

```
<?php
$str = "dateto:'2015-10-07 15:05' xxxx datefrom:'2015-10-09 15:05' yyyy asdf";
$matches = preg_split('/(?<!\d)(\s)/', $str);
print_r($matches);
```

---

Output:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => dateto:'2015-10-07 15:05'
        [1] => xxxx
        [2] => datefrom:'2015-10-09 15:05'
        [3] => yyyy
        [4] => asdf
    )
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/EP06Nt

---

Regex Explanation:

```
(?<!\d)(\s)

Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!\d)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\s)»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s»
```

Comment: Thank you! ok "negative lookback" but where the hack is the ` ' ` defined?? how could I change if `dateto:"has-double-quotes"`?